# non-static variable newJourney cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, object, methods, static

Ive trying to build some code and keep running into this error. Ive tried ways around it but it then messes with the execution of methods within Journey.

Ive looked at other threads but cant seem to find an answer.

```
class Main{
private Journey newJourney;

public static void main(String[] args){
        startStation.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener(){
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                    if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){

                        String selectedItem = startStation.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        newJourney = new Journey();
                        newJourney.setStart(selectedItem);


                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

Obviously ommited some code but thats the main just of things.

Any help is appreciated and the error im recieveing is

```
Main.java:102: non-static variable newJourney cannot be referenced from a static context
                        newJourney.setStart(selectedItem);
                        ^
```

Comment: Take a look to the right, in `Related` section. If those aren't enough, nothing anyone can do here will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all.  newJourney is not a static variable where main is a static method.  This means main cannot access it.  This means the following code will not work

```
private Journey newJourney;
```

you would need

```
private static Journey newJourney;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your object as a `sataic` one as following:

```
private static Journey newJourney;
```

Because you are using this object in a `non-static` way, It must be a `static` one

Answer (score 0):

`newJourney` is not static, you are trying to access into static methods.

As a Java concept, an object's state can not be changed inside static methods.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to adopt the following paradigm, in which you create a new object for the class that your static Main method is in, and then do all your work from that object.

```
class Main{
private static final Main me;
private Journey newJourney;

public static void main(String[] args){
    me = new Main();
    me.doWork(args);
}
private void doWork(String[] args) {
    startStation.addItemListener(
        new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    String selectedItem = startStation.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    newJourney = new Journey();
                    newJourney.setStart(selectedItem);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```